# Sitecore: Drop Down Search Menu

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, sitecore, sitecore8

I am in need of hopefully an example for a drop down list search function. Not sure what the correct terminology would be.

Needed:
Two drop down lists then a submit button. First being of Country, then the second being of Department. So say you picked France and HR, it would display a contact person below.

Is there any examples of something of this sort? Would be nice have code in CS then have my end user be able to add and link the two together in Sitecore. So they could add Countries they would like, departments they would like, then the respected person linked to the two fields.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you're taking multiple inputs and producing results for that combination of them. I'll make some assumptions and try to give you enough direction to get started. This will take a bit of explaining.

Starting from scratch, we've got a Contact template that has, at least, a Country and Department field. You'll need templates and lists of items for each of those two fields. You could get these values from another source, but let's just keep it simple for now and use lists of items. This sounds hierarchical, so I'd suggest you define your departments as children of your Country items. What other fields are on these items doesn't really matter at the moment.

Next, you'll want to communicate the end-user's selections back to your Sitecore instance. I'll assume that you're using Sitecore MVC, but the same principles apply for web forms.

Set up a controller to parse your parameters, `country` and `department`, and a form in your View with `<select>` elements populated from the lists of countries and departments. When the country selector is changed, you can either reload the page with the value set as a request parameter or use AJAX to ask your controller directly. If you structure the model so that it doesn't rely on the rendering context, you can submit your form results to `/api/sitecore/{controllername}/{actionname}?country={values}&department={values}` and get the data that way. (If you want an example of the kind of JS you need to do this I can provide one.) You could disable or hide the Department `<select>` until this is selected so that users don't get confused, then use the same technique to also set the Department parameter/submit that value. Once those two values are in the request, you have enough information to get a list or single Contact and display that information, also using the same technique.

If you have a more specific question about a particular aspect of this process I'd be happy to explain.